# Mysql server crash in windows

Tags: mysql, crash

mysql server was running since 3 months and I receive the following message, Can you please helpe me ?

I checked the logs and I find crash info, in my data folder of mysql I have a lot of files like this : LAPTOP-ACSUNASU-bin.000025 and I have a folder called #innodb_redo , which contain a lot of files like that #ib_redo606_tmp.

```
C:\MySQL80\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.34) starting as process 38188
2023-12-05T14:18:34.155395Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-12-05T14:18:35.237148Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-12-05T14:18:35.777992Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2023-12-05T14:18:35.784262Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2023-12-05T14:18:35.879917Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-12-05T14:18:35.880514Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-12-05T14:18:35.925789Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2023-12-05T14:18:35.925857Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\MySQL80\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.34'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-12-05T14:18:37.621218Z 11 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: btr0pcur.cc:336:btr_page_get_prev(next_page, mtr) == get_block()->page.id.page_no() thread 28428
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-12-05T14:18:37Z UTC - mysqld got exception 0x16 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x23364d63c00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff7cfa7a418    mysqld.exe!?my_print_stacktrace@@YAXPEBEK@Z()
7ff7cebee841    mysqld.exe!?print_fatal_signal@@YAXH@Z()
7ff7cebee583    mysqld.exe!?my_server_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7cfa5c6aa    mysqld.exe!?my_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7cfc2f4d9    mysqld.exe!?do_reset@Zstd_dec@compression@transaction@binary_log@@EEAAXXZ()
7ff7cfd75f2b    mysqld.exe!?do_reset@Zstd_dec@compression@transaction@binary_log@@EEAAXXZ()
7ff7cfcba38e    mysqld.exe!?do_reset@Zstd_dec@compression@transaction@binary_log@@EEAAXXZ()
7ff7cfcbdf1d    mysqld.exe!?do_reset@Zstd_dec@compression@transaction@binary_log@@EEAAXXZ()
7ff7cfab84bf    mysqld.exe!?do_reset@Zstd_dec@compression@transaction@binary_log@@EEAAXXZ()
7ff7ce9b6beb    mysqld.exe!?ha_index_next_same@handler@@QEAAHPEAEPEBEI@Z()
7ff7ceefc51d    mysqld.exe!?Read@?$RefIterator@$0A@@@UEAAHXZ()
7ff7ceef95d7    mysqld.exe!?Read@FilterIterator@@UEAAHXZ()
7ff7ced7a14c    mysqld.exe!?ExecuteIteratorQuery@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7ced7b623    mysqld.exe!?execute@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7cec5312e    mysqld.exe!?execute_inner@Sql_cmd_dml@@MEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7cec52fbe    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7ceba783a    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7ced31308    mysqld.exe!?execute@Prepared_statement@@AEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVString@@_N@Z()
7ff7ced31706    mysqld.exe!?execute_loop@Prepared_statement@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVString@@_N@Z()
7ff7ced337b3    mysqld.exe!?mysqld_stmt_execute@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAVPrepared_statement@@_NKPEAUPS_PARAM@@@Z()
7ff7ceba0e8f    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEBTCOM_DATA@@W4enum_server_command@@@Z()
7ff7ceba29b6    mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7ce9a9b28    mysqld.exe!?thread_id@THD@@QEBAIXZ()
7ff7cfffcff9    mysqld.exe!?my_init_dynamic_array@@YA_NPEAUDYNAMIC_ARRAY@@IIPEAXII@Z()
7ff7cfa6ac0c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_self_setname@@YAXPEBD@Z()
7fffb7721bb2    ucrtbase.dll!_configthreadlocale()
7fffb7d27344    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7fffb9b026b1    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (2330d9c0af8): select serverstat0_.id as col_0_0_ from spt_server_statistic serverstat0_ where serverstat0_.created<=1701181117593 and serverstat0_.host='c0a8016b8a1819a2818a186aa4fd02bf'
Connection ID (thread ID): 11
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```